# What does (id,title)=line.split('|')[0:2] do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I just started learning python and I picked up a book that is written in python 2 but I am using python3.6 to compile. So I am not very familiar with the differences.

When I wrote this

```
movies={}
for line in open (path+'/u.item'):
    (id,title)=line.split('|')[0:2]
    movies[id]=title
```

I get this error

```
   (id,title)=line.split('|')[0:2]     
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

I'm not quite sure what    (id,title)=line.split("|")[0:2]  is doing. Please help me understand.

Comment: `id,title = line.split('|')[0:2]` ?

Comment: line.split will return a list. you can only access list element with the help of integer indices

Comment: @Rakesh yeah it's suppose to be [0:2] but I still get the same error. I don't understand what is happening in that line.

Comment: Changing `[0.2]` to `[0:2]` should fix the error..

Comment: @Rakesh still getting the same error

Comment: Can you print `line.split('|')` to show us what it looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like each `line` is supposed to be a string with one or more pipe characters (`|`).

e.g. `line = "This|is|an|example"`

`line.split('|')` splits the string into an array (which Python calls a "list") at every occurrence of the *delimiter*. The delimiter is the string passed as an argument to `split()`, which in this case is the pipe character.

So, in my example, `line.split('|')` returns `['This', 'is', 'an', 'example']`.

The brackets at the end are saying "Now that we've split the string into an array, give me every item in that array, from index 0 up to—but not including!—index 2." (In other words, give me the first two items in the array.)

Continuing my example, `line.split('|')[0:2]` returns `['This', is']`.

The `=` symbol assigns the returned values (`'This'` and `'is'`) to `id` and `title`, respectively.

The result is `id == 'This'` and `title == 'is'`.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. ^_^